# Cannot install iOS SDK for RAD Studio 10.2 Tokyo

Tags: ios, delphi, delphi-10.2-tokyo, rad-studio, paserver

We recently purchased a new license of RAD Studio Tokyo and installed version 10.2 Update 3 on Windows 10 Pro. We purchased the product specifically for the capability of targeting both Windows and iOS, but so far we can only target Windows.

The target environment is macOS 10.13.6, with all latest updates including Xcode 10.1 and iPhoneOS12.1.sdk, iPhoneSimulator12.1.sdk, MacOSX10.14.sdk. Also installed is PAServer-19.0.app and PAServerManager.app, which both run as expected.

After following [the RAD Studio docs to setup a connection profile and iOS SDK](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Adding_an_OS_X_or_iOS_SDK), I was able to connect to PAServer, it parsed the available SDKs (`/usr/bin/xcodebuild -version -sdk`). The **Add a New SDK** dialog in RAD Studio then populates the **Select an SDK version** combobox with what it parsed, but it only lists the macOS SDK "MacOSX 10.14". There is no iOS SDK listed.

I then read [the supported iOS target environments](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Supported_Target_Platforms) and saw iOS 12 is unsupported. So I downloaded Xcode 9.4.1 from Apple (which includes iOS 11.4 SDK), assuming iOS 11.4 would be supported since the RAD Studio docs say iOS 11 is supported.

Following [the troubleshooting docs](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/SDK_Manager#Troubleshooting_.28OS_X_and_iOS.29), I installed Xcode 9.4.1 to a standalone directory (leaving the existing Xcode 10.1 alone in /Applications), updated the system selected Xcode (using `/usr/bin/xcode-select --switch /path/to/Xcode-9.4.1.app/Contents/Developer`), then restarted PAServer.

Now when I try to select the supported version of iOS through the **Add a New SDK** dialog in RAD Studio, the **Select an SDK version** combobox is populated with the newly-installed older macOS SDK "MacOSX 10.13", so I'm confident it is looking in the correct paths, but there is *still* no iOS SDK listed. What gives?

Comment: Have you started the Xcode 9 version after the download? Some components are installed on the first start. At least it did so on my machine.

Comment: Yeah -- I've created a dummy project and verified it was able to run in iOS Simulator with Xcode 9.4.1 and iOS Simulator 11.4 SDK. Granted, this is different than the actual iOS SDK, but regardless RAD Studio should have then listed the Simulator SDK as available in this case, right?

Comment: Do your Xcode 9 path have spaces? I had problems with the foldername "XCode 9" and Delphi.

Comment: When adding an SDK using Delphi's SDK Manager, does it list iOS as one of the platforms? If not, and you installed via ESD (i.e. not via an ISO), you should go to Tools|Manage Platforms and ensure that the iOS platform is selected. If it was installed via an ISO, you'd need to uninstall, and reinstall with iOS platform selected

Comment: @DaveNottage Hmm, no it doesn't. I installed via ISO (it is an air-gapped network, no Internet connectivity). When I run the installer, iOS isn't even listed under `Embarcadero RAD Studio > Additional Platform Support`. It only lists `OS X` and `Windows 64-bit`...

Comment: @ardnew Have you installed Delphi Mobile Pack Add-On after installing Delphi which you now get for free with professional version of Delphi 10.2.3 or newer? During installation of Delphi 10.2.3 installer does not offer installation of Delphi Mobile Pack Add-on as one of the installation components and has to be installed manually after the installation of Delphi. https://community.embarcadero.com/article/articles-support/174-rad-studio/installation-registration/16617-delphi-and-c-builder-10-2-3-tokyo-professional-edition-mobile-pack-install-instructions-4

Comment: Without the Delphi Mobile Pack Add-on you won't be able to develop applications for any mobile platforms whether this is iOS or Android.

Comment: @SilverWarior while that add-on used to be a required separate download/install, they now include it *pre-installed* with Delphi, C++Builder, and RAD Studio (Professional and greater). It is **not** a required separate package. An Embarcadero sales rep made that a significant talking point with us. Check again the link you posted, it confirms this.

Comment: @ardnew When I was upgrading from Delphi 10.2.2 to Delphi 10.2.3 I had to install the Mobile Add-on Pack separately since during the upgrade I wasn't offered the ability to install Mobile pack Add-on. It is possible that Embarcadero updated their installer later on to simplify this as at the time there were lots o complaints about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We've had a hell of a time with Embarcadero licensing over the last couple of years, and this seems to be an extension of that.

Taking note of @DaveNottage's comment, I thought it was weird `iOS` wasn't listed as an available platform through the ISO installer and remembered how older versions of RAD Studio used to offer it as a "Mobile Pack Add-On", but only for certain *editions*. Then I compared my installed edition of RAD Studio (Professional) to the edition named in our new Network Named User license (Enterprise). Those don't match. So I launched the license manager, verified that indeed I have 2 different licenses installed, and that RAD Studio 10.2 was apparently using the older, inferior XE8 *Professional* license, since it was covered under their upgrade licensing.

I deleted this license from the license manager. Uninstalled RAD Studio 10.2. Re-installed using the exact same ISO I used originally. And now suddenly I have iOS 32-bit and 64-bit as available platforms, and they also now appear as available SDKs in the SDK Manager.

---

And for the record, you guys were much more help than Embarcadero Support. I submitted this exact same issue (copy-pasted), and their only response was that RAD Studio 10.2 doesn't support iOS 12 and to contact their sales team about access to the beta release of RAD Studio 10.3. So they clearly didn't even read the issue **at all**. Wonderful support for a $5000 license.

Comment: I wish I could up vote this a million times.  Embarcadero plain sucks.  Their products suck and their support sucks.  It's amazing they are even still in business.  We are stuck with the product for so long I, foolishly, pulled the trigger on them again to play around with Firemonkey.  Built a couple apps with trial-ware but when it came time to purchase the enterprise version, it was problem after problem just getting it installed.  We paid for a 10.2 (tokyo) version and trying to upgrade to 10.3, as my license entitles me too, it simply does not work at all!  So done with this company.